# Not getting list of parse object I am fetching from parse

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

I am using this code for getting a row from the parse cloud but everytime I am fetching objects it is giving me empty list,Although there is a corresponding row available in the parse which I am trying to find and update.

```
      public void onClick(View v) {
      ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("StudentInfo");
      query.whereEqualTo("rollnum",rollnum.getText().toString());
      query.whereEqualTo("name",name.getText().toString());
      query.whereEqualTo("city",city.getText().toString());
      query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
      @Override
      public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

                    if(e == null && objects.size() > 0){
                    obj=objects.get(0);
                    obj.put("rollnum",rollnum.getText()
                            .toString());
                    obj.put("name",name.getText().toString());
                    obj.put("city", city.getText().toString());
                    obj.saveInBackground();
                   }
                    else if(objects.size()==0){
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No relation     Found!"+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }

                }
              }
```

If the object is  there I am updating it with new values with help of put method.But it is always giving me an empty list of Parse Objects.

Comment: have you debugged the rollnum.getText().toString() etc. values to make sure they are what you were expecting?

Comment: Also I don't know if you have just made a mistake when uploading your code, but I believe the last two brackets should be });

Comment: Yes I debugged and everything which I am passing to query.whereEqualto() is correct.I toasted the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to update the available objects.You can do it this way.

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("StudentInfo");
  query.whereEqualTo("rollnum",rollnum.getText().toString());
  query.whereEqualTo("name",name.getText().toString());
  query.whereEqualTo("city",city.getText().toString());
  query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
  @Override
  public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

                if(e == null ){
                if(object.size()==0){
              //here you can put object with help of put method if object is not there and when the object size is greater than 1 you remove the other objects except the objects.get(0).All other objects except one will be removed and only the zeroth object will be updated at the time user updates it
                 } 
                else if( objects.size() > 0){
                obj=objects.get(0);
                obj.put("rollnum",rollnum.getText()
                        .toString());
                obj.put("name",name.getText().toString());
                obj.put("city", city.getText().toString());
                obj.saveInBackground();
               }
             }
            else{
                  //exception in getting data
             }

            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a empty list of objects then that means there are no objects stored that match the criteria that you are querying against.

Make sure you understand your query. The way you are setting up your query, there has to be a ParseObject stored where the rollnum, name, and city are equal to those values you are testing against, and they must be exactly equal. If no objects match that criteria, then parse will return an empty list. Use the Logcat and Parse Dashboard to debug and find out what's wrong with your query.